# How to install php55-php-mcrypt with scl-utils?

Tags: php, centos, mcrypt, centos7

It's a known fact that on Fedora/RHEL/CentOS 7.x based systems PHP 5.4.16 is the supported version. However, for my application I needed PHP 5.5 and I installed it from RHEL-recommended scl-utils repository as explained on https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Developer_Guide/scl-utils.html

The problem is that I have successfully installed all required packages except `php55-php-mcrypt`:

```
yum install php55-php-mcrypt
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.sonic.net
 * epel: mirror.hmc.edu
 * extras: mirror.keystealth.org
 * updates: mirrors.easynews.com
No package php55-php-mcrypt available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Could anyone recommend a way to get this package installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explanation why "mcrypt" is a very bad idea, and is not part of standard repository : [About libmcrypt and php-mcrypt](http://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/07/07/About-libmcrypt-and-php-mcrypt)

For people who want to use the official **RHSCL** packages on RHEL (which is also available in **centos-scl** repository), you can find additional packages in the community repositories:

- php55 => [php55more](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/remi/php55more/)
- rh-php56 => [php56more](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/remi/php56more/)

Else, yes my repository is an alternative, see the [Configuration Wizard](http://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

Comment: From what I can tell, the mcrypt extension is not included in either php55more or php56more (both of which are deprecated).

Comment: @JayK this answer is 1 year old ;)  Indeed php56more is now deprecated, and "sclo" repository should be prefered (read https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2017/02/23/Additional-PHP-packages-for-RHSCL). BTW php56more have it, and we are working on a solution to be able to provide it in "sclo". See https://www.softwarecollections.org/repos/remi/php56more/epel-7-x86_64/more-php56-php-extras-5.6.5-2.remi/

Answer (score 1):

Switch to the [Remi repo](http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en). It has 5.5, 5.6 and 7.0 available and they are supported as long as the PHP project supports them. Better still, he breaks that support into separate repos, so you pick the one you want and install the `php-*` RPMs. When you're ready to upgrade, enable the next repo and just `yum update`.

> RPM of PHP version 7.0.2 are available in remi-php70 repository for Fedora and Enterprise Linux (RHEL, CentOS).
>
> RPM of PHP version 5.6.17 are available in remi repository for Fedora ≥ 21 and  remi-php56 repository for Fedora and Enterprise Linux.
>
> RPM of PHP version 5.5.31 are available in remi repository for Fedora 20 and in remi-php55 repository for  Enterprise Linux.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to my repository. But I think my additional answer is needed. 1/ to explain why "mcrypt" is a bad idea. 2/ to give a solution for people who wants to use RH supported packages before any 3rd party repository (well... in all case, they will use my work ;)